# How can I use python and webdriver to monitor the browser console log messages as they update?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to write a test where I wait until a certain message is written to the browser console log. Once a timeout is reached, it should finish waiting.

I am able to fetch the console log output (using python and webdriver) once. My code is this:

```
@when("I reach the end of the movie")
def step_impl(context):

    start_ts = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_ts < 180:
        if is_finished_playing(context):
            break
        time.sleep(0.2)

def is_finished_playing(context):
    for entry in context.browser.get_log('browser'):
        print(entry['message'])
        if "Finished Playing" in entry['message']:
            return True
```

However, it works only once for what the browser showed until I call the `is_finished_playing()` function at first. I can't seem to figure out how to keep polling the console log for further updates.

Also - as you can see, I'm not using WebDriverWait although it seems like the obvious choice. I wasn't able to make it work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps try changing the break to pass, or get rid of the if statement altogether?